# Flink Job not getting submitted. java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am using Flink session cluster(Kubernetes Cluster (Session Mode)) to deploy batch jobs with HA. Inside the recovery/default/blob/ directory, directories starting with job_ is getting piled up.

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 flink flink 1 Nov 16 09:03 job_747a694a765d1b580a703e2785a9e3fa
```

Job get submitted every 1 min. But in the above above ls -ltr of /recovery/default/blob/, blobs of one of the job is not getting cleared. This job has neither completed nor failed. Also it is not listed in the list on the web ui

The log file when this happens is

```
2021-11-22 09:03:11,537 INFO  org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServices [] - Finished cleaning up the high availability data for job 6a71a36a3c82d8a9438c9aa9ed6b8993.
2021-11-22 09:03:14,904 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection           [] - PUT operation failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataOutputStream.write(LocalDataOutputStream.java:55) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:113) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:243) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:301) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:79) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:72) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobUtils.moveTempFileToStore(BlobUtils.java:385) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer.moveTempFileToStore(BlobServer.java:680) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.put(BlobServerConnection.java:350) [flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.run(BlobServerConnection.java:110) [flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
```

It seems that Flink is not retrying this job. Is there a config which can retry this job?

Comment: Is this job that's actually running ? Seems like the problem might be the jar submission so the failure is not really recoverable.

Comment: No the job does not run. We are deploying the  batch jobs every minute(same jar). The jobs run and completes 99% of the time. But the same job sometimes fails with the above error.